# PHP foreach sorting every 9 items into lists and divs

Tags: php, foreach

Im currently struggle with sorting a foreach loop into its own div's and ul's, heres what i have currently:

```
<ul class="thumbnails parts-page">
<?php $show = false; ?>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
    <?php if($item->state == 1 || ($item->state == 0 && JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.own',' com_parts'))):
        $show = true;
    ?>
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="<?php echo $item->brand_link; ?>" style="background:url(<?php echo $item->brand_image; ?>) no-repeat center center #FFF; "  class="thumbnail parts" target="_blank">
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

basically this produces:

```
<ul class="thumbnails parts-page">
            <li class="span4">
            <a href="http://www.canecreek.com/" style="background: url('/torqzone/images/brands/cane-creek.png') no-repeat center center #FFF; "  class="thumbnail parts" target="_blank">
            </a>
        </li>

            <li class="span4">
            <a href="http://www.amclassic.com/en/" style="background: url('/torqzone/images/brands/american-classic.png') no-repeat center center #FFF; "  class="thumbnail parts" target="_blank">
            </a>
        </li>

            <li class="span4">
            <a href="http://www.avid.com/US/" style="background: url('/torqzone/images/brands/avid.png') no-repeat center center #FFF; "  class="thumbnail parts" target="_blank">
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

but i need to split it so that every 9 items is in its own:

```
<ul class="thumbnails parts-page">
9ITEMS
</ul>
```

I have tried various solution that i found online but nothing seems to work..

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: What are some of the solutions you've tried? Do they include a counter and the `<ul>` tags *inside* the foreach loop?

Comment: yes but then that it becomes like a ul in a ul in a ul and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very easy and readable solution is to use [array_chunk](http://de3.php.net/manual/function.array-chunk.php):

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($this->items, 9) as $items): ?>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>     
      <!-- your code -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Yes it's an extra loop, but so much more readable.

Comment: Yeah I was glad you took this out of the comments and into the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
echo '<ul ...>';
$i = 0;
foreach ( ...... ) {
  if (++$i % 9 == 0) echo '</ul><ul ....>';

  // your code here

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable equal to 1. increment it every time you run your loop. If its > 9, create a new ul, else add it to the old ul.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$i=0;
foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
    <?php if($item->state == 1 || ($item->state == 0 && JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.own',' com_parts'))):
        $show = true;
++$i;    
?>
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="<?php echo $item->brand_link; ?>" style="background:url(<?php echo $item->brand_image; ?>) no-repeat center center #FFF; "  class="thumbnail parts" target="_blank">
            </a>
        </li>
<?php if($i>8): $i=0; ?>
</ul><ul class="thumbnails parts-page">
<?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

instead of above code replace this

Comment: Also reset `$i` once it's `>8`

Answer (score 0):

How about using a counter variable?

```
$counter = 0;
<?php $show = false; ?>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
    <?php if ($counter % 9 == 0) 
         echo '<ul class="thumbnails parts-page">';?>


    <?php if($item->state == 1 || ($item->state == 0 && JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.own',' com_parts'))):
        $show = true;
    ?>
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="<?php echo $item->brand_link; ?>" style="background:url(<?php echo $item->brand_image; ?>) no-repeat center center #FFF; "  class="thumbnail parts" target="_blank">
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>

   <?php if ($counter % 9 == 0) 
         echo '</ul>';?>

<?php $counter +=1 ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In this way you will print the **ul** tags every 9 items of your list (putting them inside).
(PLease test the code since I do not have a environment for it right now)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to accomplish this is to create a counter that goes up by one every time. For example at the start of your code declare $count and the in your for each statement say $count++. You can then create a IF statement that says  if the count is 9, create the new UL.

Seems like people are trying to make this too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

From your what I understand is you want is every unordered list must contain only 9 items.. If thats the case you can use a count variable

```
<?php $show = false; $count=0; ?>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
    <?php if($item->state == 1 || ($item->state == 0 && JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.own',' com_parts'))):
        $show = true;
    ?>
 <?php if($count%9==0) echo'<ul class="thumbnails parts-page">'; ?>
        <li class="span4">
            <a href="<?php echo $item->brand_link; ?>" style="background:url(<?php echo $item->brand_image; ?>) no-repeat center center #FFF; "  class="thumbnail parts" target="_blank">
            </a>
        </li>
  <?php if($count%9 ==0) echo '</ul>'; ?>
   <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```